# MySQL select from 3 tables order by date

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

i have 3 tables audios,videos,images

they all have dateadded and uid

i want to select all (select *) from these tables where uid=1 and order all the results by dateadded, very confused what the query  would be like?

Comment: do table have the same fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if tha tables hold the same information you can use union, e.g.:

```
select name, date_added
from(
  select video_name as name,date_added, uid
  from videos
  union all
  select audio_name as name,date_added, uid
  from audios
  union all
  select image_name as name,date_added, uid
  from images
) u
where uid = 1
order by date_added
```

Comment: i want to do something like this:

select *
from(
  select * from files_video union all 
  select * from files_audio union all
  select * from files_image
) u where uid =$uid order by adddate;

but some tables have different name of cols

Comment: how do i do it if i dont want to union all but just a video_name and adddate ?

Answer (score 0):

If the 3 table has 1 same field like groupID or something like that you can use left join or inner join depending on what output would you want to have.

using left join:

```
select * from videos v left join audios a on v.groupID = a.groupID
left join images i on v.groupID = i.groupID
```

note:
just change the word "left" to "inner" if you want to use the other type of join.
It doesn't have to have the same field name "groupID". But it is necessary to have a common functionality or it represents something which is related to each other.

Links:
here are some links that may help you
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

enjoy coding..:)

Comment: what about where uid=1 and order by dateadded? where do i put these? in the beginning?

Comment: you may add it on and after the where clause repectively like: "select ... where uid = 1 order by dateadded"